# Guessing game - Is it a 40?

Tags: java, beginner, swing, binary-search, number-guessing-game

User has number in head, the program must guess the number.

```
public class GuessingGame extends JFrame{

    JButton newGameButton, highButton, lowButton, correctButton, exitButton;
    JLabel initialTextLabel, enterLabel;
    JTextArea commentTextArea;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    private int guess, high = 101, low = 0, tries = 1;

    public guessingGame()
    {
        title("Guessing Game");
        newGameButton = new JButton("Start Game");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit Game");
        highButton = new JButton("Too High");
        lowButton = new JButton("Too Low");
        correctButton = new JButton("Correct!");

        commentTextArea = new JTextArea(null,10,30);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(commentTextArea);
        commentTextArea.setEditable(false);
        initialTextLabel = new JLabel("Think of a number between 0 & 100 can the computer guess it");
        enterLabel = new JLabel("Is your number: ");


        //add components


        highButton.setVisible(false);
        lowButton.setVisible(false);
        correctButton.setVisible(false);


        //set default jframe size

        //create and register the button event handlers


    }//end of GuessGame constructor

    //highButtonHandler class
    class highButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                high = guess;
                guess = low + (guess - low) / 2;
                tries++;
                commentTextArea.append("Is the number " + guess + " too small, too high or correct.\n");
        }
    }//end of high class

    //lowButtonHandler class
    class lowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                low = guess;
                guess = guess + (high - guess) / 2;
                tries++;
                commentTextArea.append("Is the number " + guess + " too small, too high or correct.\n");
            }
        }//end of low class

    //correctButtonHandler class
    class correctButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                commentTextArea.append("The computer took " + tries + " tries to guess your number");
            }
        }//end of correct class

    //newGame ButtonHandler class
    class newGameButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            commentTextArea.setText(null); //clear textArea
            //reset values
            guess = 50;
            tries = 1;
            low = 0;
            high = 101;

            commentTextArea.append("Is the number " + guess +" too small, too high or correct.\n");
            newGameButton.setText("Start New Game"); //set button text
        }
    }//end of newGame class

    //exitButtonHandler class
    class exitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        guessingGame myGuessGame = new guessingGame(); //instantiate a GUI object
        myGuessGame.setVisible(true);
    }//end main
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pros

- dedicated classes for the ActionListener
- calls `JFramw.setVisible()` from outside any constructor

### cons

- **Naming conventions**: class names always start with upper case letter
- **Inheritance**: never extend a class unless you want to change *behavior*, you only *configure* JFrame, so no need to extend it.
- **comments**: comments in code should explain *why* the code is like it is and only if it is somewhat unusual or unexpected. Your comments only repeat what the code expresses already.
- **System.exit(0);**: This kills the JVM. There will be no change to i.e. close database connections correctly. Use it only in a catch block inside `main`.

Comment: What do you mean about Inheritance part. I wish to break the program into classes to be used in another program i am working on, how wouldi do this.

Comment: @joe your code is ` class GuessingGame extends JFrame` this means your class `GuessingGame` *extends* the library class `JFrame`. But you do not add new behavior to how a Frame works, you add your business solution which is *using* the JFrame.